# Как заставить код игнорировать MessageBox и продолжить свою работу?

Tags: c#

Я хочу, чтобы код не ждал ответа от пользователя на MessageBox и продолжил выполнение. То есть игнорировал MessageBox.
Вот код:

```
MessageBox.Show("Chrome error occurred", "Chrome", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
Process.Start("taskkill", "/f /im chrome.exe");
```

Comment: Не используйте в таком случае `MessageBox`, в чем проблема? Пишите вместо этого например логи. Либо поменяйте эти 2 строчки местами.

Comment: @aepot я как пример написал

Comment: `MessageBox` - это диалог, он о чем-то спрашивает пользователя, и код без ответа не может продолжаться, это нормальная логика. Но вопрос очень общий, бывают разные ситуации, где-то выполнение кода можно вынести в отдельный поток, где-то вместо бокса использовать логирование в файл или в текстбокс. Но допускать ситуацию, когда приложение выплюнет более одного бокса на экран - не следует.

Answer (score 0):

По идее можно воспользоваться свойством [`MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), которое изменит родителя окна на рабочий стол. После этого сам процесс должен будет продолжиться, не ожидая при этом ответа окна.

Comment: Пошел чайку попить - вернулся, и весь десктоп в этих попапах в 4 слоя. :)

Comment: всё равно не работает, не продолжается код